# cron vs anacron on server machine (AWS instance)

Tags: cron

During review of environment which I took over I've discovered that Amazon Linux uses anacron by default which means that cron.weekly jobs are executed **somewhere between 3a.m. and 10p.m**. Moreover - I've found that weekly jobs are **executed twice**: every Wednesday and every Sunday. The /etc/anacron looks like default one:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
# the maximal random delay added to the base delay of the jobs
RANDOM_DELAY=45
# the jobs will be started during the following hours only
START_HOURS_RANGE=3-22

#period in days   delay in minutes   job-identifier   command
1       5       cron.daily              nice run-parts /etc/cron.daily
7       25      cron.weekly             nice run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly 45     cron.monthly            nice run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
```

I have one important and one not important question according to this:

1. [Important] Is it a good practice to use **anacron** on server with e.g. shorter time frame (1a.m.-5a.m. instead of 3a.m.-10p.m.) or I should switch to **cron**?
2. [Not important] Why weekly tasks are executed **twice** a week? (/var/spool/cron/ is empty, /etc/crontab have no entries; /var/log/messages contains only DHCP requests entries, /var/log/cron contains info that it will run the job)

Thanks in advance!
Alx

Comment: anacron is only useful for systems that aren't running 24/7. That said I can't explain why it would run weekly jobs twice a week. Two anacron processes running perhaps?